# FeatureNotFound: Couldn't find a tree builder with the features you requested: lxml. Do you need to install a parser library?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, jupyter-notebook, lxml, sentiment-analysis

I try to running this code to process "teks". And it show 
FeatureNotFound: Couldn't find a tree builder with the features you requested: lxml. Do you need to install a parser library?

```
def proses_teks(teks):
soup = BeautifulSoup(teks, "lxml") 
souped = soup.get_text()
try:
    teks = souped.decode("utf-8-sig").replace(u"\ufffd", "?")
except:
    teks = souped
teks_bersih= re.sub("[^a-zA-Z0-9]", " ",(re.sub(www_pat, '', re.sub(combined_pat, '', teks)).lower()))
teks_bersih= ' '.join([word for word in teks_bersih.split() if word not in stopword_user])
return (" ".join([x for x in tok.tokenize(teks_bersih) if len(x) > 1])).strip()

 teks='''hahaha apakah SAYA ingin pergi pada tanggal 15 bulan februari besok ? tidak karena
hari kemarin @twitter suka main https://www.twitter.com'''

proses_teks(teks)
```

error:

```
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
FeatureNotFound                           Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-83-334183dacf47> in <module>
----> 1 proses_teks(teks)

<ipython-input-81-598b2eb2c340> in proses_teks(teks)
      1 def proses_teks(teks):
----> 2     soup = BeautifulSoup(teks, "lxml")
      3     souped = soup.get_text()
      4     try:
      5         teks = souped.decode("utf-8-sig").replace(u"\ufffd", "?")

c:\users\blabla\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\lib\site-packages\bs4\__init__.py in __init__(self, markup, features, builder, parse_only, from_encoding, exclude_encodings, element_classes, **kwargs)
    214                     "Couldn't find a tree builder with the features you "
    215                     "requested: %s. Do you need to install a parser library?"
--> 216                     % ",".join(features))
    217 
    218         # At this point either we have a TreeBuilder instance in

FeatureNotFound: Couldn't find a tree builder with the features you requested: lxml. Do you need to install a parser library?
```

I already read some of this error, and it said that i should change

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(teks, "lxml")
```

to

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "lxml")
```

but the error come up again and said `NameError: name 'html' is not defined`

What should i do?

Comment: `BeautifulSoup` is for html, not text. And why do you even need it? just do `teks = teks.replace(u"\ufffd", "?")`

Comment: What are you trying to do here? As @Guy said, BeautifulSoup is an HTML parser.

Comment: oh my bad :') thank you for your answer, it works!

Comment: This is a red herring. You shouldn't be using BS to parse plain non-HTML/XML text.